# Python: take multiples based on condition

Tags: python, numpy, range, slice

Is there a Way in Python to have a for loop which cycle only on multiples of a given number that are not multiples of any number lower than given number?

I mean something like this:

`if given_number = 13` 
the for loop is going to cycle only on `[13 * 13, 13 * 17, 13 * 19, 13 * 23, 13*29, 13*31, 13*39, ........]`

I came across this kind of problem working on this function:

```
def get_primes_lower_n(n: int) -> List[int]:
   """
      n: int
         the given input number
      returns: List[int]
         all primes number lower than given input number
      raises:
         ValueError: the given input is an integer < 2
         TypeError: the given input is not an integer
   """
   if not isinstance(n, int):
      raise TypeError("an integer is required")
   if n < 2:
      raise ValueError("an integer > 1 is required")
   primes = np.ones(n + 1, dtype=bool)  # bool(1) = True
   primes[:2] = False
   primes[4:: 2] = False
   for i in range(3, isqrt(n) + 1, 2):
      if primes[i]:
         primes[i ** 2:: 2 * i] = False
   return np.where(primes == True)[0]
```

if `n` is something like `9 * 10 ** 9` the algorithm is going to explode. For any value of I `primes[i ** 2:: 2 * i] = False` is going to take more or less 52 seconds. Let's think of `I = 7`; `primes[i ** 2:: 2 * i] = False`
is going to set to `False` all values in positions multiples of 21 and 35 that are already set to False.

As the value of I increases, I expect the time of execution of this operation `primes[i ** 2:: 2 * i] = False` to take less time (less values need to be set), but instead it increases exponentially. Why?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question:

> Is there a Way in python to have a for loop which cycle only on multiples of a given number that are not multiples of any number lower than given number?

Yes there is, but not efficient enough (unless you find a faster implementation).

Let n be the number we are looking at.

The *numbers that are not multiples of any number lower than n* are exactly the numbers left from the sieve when ran up to n. Therefore, these numbers are already present in the array, they are the `True` values with index greater than n. Unfortunately, as these are stored by index, finding them is expensive and finally makes the code go slower, as the collisions from the original algorithm are so rare. Still, here is a possible implementation in the for loop.

```
for i in range(3, isqrt(n) + 1, 2):
    primes[i*(np.nonzero(primes[i:n//i])[0]+i)] = False
    # [i:n//i] is to bound the search from i to the last number such
    # that i*(n//i) < n.
```

Here is an equivalent code without the bool array:

```
def get_primes_lower_n(n: int) -> list[int]:
    primes = np.arange(3, n + 1, 2) # only odd numbers over 3
    val = 0
    idx = -1
    while val <= isqrt(n)+1:
        idx += 1
        val = primes[idx]
        primes = np.setdiff1d(primes, val*primes[idx:idx+bisect.bisect_left(primes[idx:], n//val+1)])
    return np.insert(primes, 0, 2)
```

As a conclusion, it is worth it to set the same values multiple times rather than use an exact approch that is slower.

Sorry for the lack of working solution but i hope this can help you in some way. If you find an interesting algorithm, feel free to let me know!

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer!!!


I asked my friend and he showed me a c++ lybraries (I did not understand if it is a python library written in C++ or a C++ library that works even in Python, I do not know C++) that seems to be awesome; if you want I will show it to you